# What is wrong with this Rspec stub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stub

I have stubbed out my API client. And have gotten it to return an expected hash. But I am not able to access the actual hash itself.

E.g

```
puts page # returns {:access_token=>"blah", :name=>"parrotcafe", :fb_id=>"2131231", :perms=>"ADMINISTER"}
```

but

```
puts page['perms'] # returns nil instead of 'ADMINISTER'
```

Here is my Rspec:

```
  describe 'all' do
    it 'if doesnt exist, it should create authentication' do
      request.env['omniauth.auth'] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]

      client = double("koala client")
      Koala::Facebook::API.stub(:new).and_return(client)
      allow(client).to receive_messages(get_connections: [{'access_token': 'blah', 'name': 'parrot', 'fb_id': '2131231', 'perms': 'ADMINISTER'}])
      expect {
        post :all, provider: :facebook
      }.to change{ Authentication.count }.by(1)
    end
  end
```

Here is the actual code where it fails.:

```
  @user_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(authentication.token)
  pages = @user_graph.get_connections('me', 'accounts')
  pages.each do |page|
    Page.create(user_id: self.id, access_token: page['access_token'], name: page['name'], fb_id: page['id']) if page['perms'].include? "ADMINISTER"
  end
```

Comment: You should use `page[:perms]` not `page['perms']`.

Comment: @Зелёный Is there a better way to go about this? Changing my code so that it passes the spec seems like a bad idea.. especially since the actual code works.

Comment: @Зелёный 'page[:perms]' doesn't seem to be the solution. still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem is that I should use used a dictionary instead:

```
allow(client).to receive_messages(get_connections: [{'access_token' => 'blah', 'name' => 'parrotcafe', 'fb_id' => '2131231', 'perms' => 'ADMINISTER'}])
```